# Android MapBox - What is the best way to add markers with info window?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

As mapbox.addMarker() is depracated I am wondering what is the best way to add marker with simple info window that is associated with the instance of the object and has click listener? I tried to use the code from Mapbox documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/

But it seems a bit too complicated though.. Is this the only way to add markers with info window?

Does anyone has any idea or link to example other than the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to add annotations to the map in Android is to use the Annotation Plugin:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/guides/annotation/

I would recommend to take a look at this example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/marker-view-plugin/

To get the same experience as in the example you have provided, you would have to add a click listener similar to how it is done in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/symbol-listener/) and only set the visibility of the `customView` that represents the text box when the symbol has been clicked.